# Bash if seemingly working differently in functions?

Tags: bash, if-statement, input

Im not experienced with bash, but i seem to run into
some random gotchas all the time when working on my scripts...

```
INPUT=""

input() {
    read -n 1 -p ":" INPUT
}

console() {
    if [[ $INPUT == "1" ]]; then
        hideMenu
        menu1
    elif [[ $INPUT == "2" ]]; then
        hideMenu
        menu2
    elif [[ $INPUT == "3" ]]; then
        hideMenu
        menu3
    elif [[ $INPUT == "menu" ]]; then
        showMenu
    elif [[ $INPUT == "q" ]]; then
        quit
    fi
}
```

This code works. it will read the input and then act according.

Then i have seemingly same thing in different file

```
J_INPUT=""

j_input() {
    read -n 1 -p ":" J_INPUT
}

console() {
    if [ $J_INPUT = "l"]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE + 1))
    elif [ $J_INPUT = "j"]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE - 1))
    elif [ $J_INPUT = "asd"]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE + 1))
    fi
}
```

This however will not run for some reason.
Also if i now try to use [[ ]] bash will throw an syntax error ?

What is wrong here? why cant i use the same syntax? what does [[ ]] valuate ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell is pretty picky about spaces around `[ ]`.

```
console() {
    if [ $J_INPUT = "l" ]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE + 1))
    elif [ $J_INPUT = "j" ]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE - 1))
    elif [ $J_INPUT = "asd" ]; then
        CURR_PAGE=$((CURR_PAGE + 1))
    fi
}
```

Comment: May also suggest a `case "$J_INPUT" in .... esac` rather than the multiple `if .. elif .. elif .. fi`

Comment: This was answer i used! but for sake of sanity, please consider python / perl / whatever before attempting to make +100 line bash script, lesson learned. anyway much thanks!